# Post apocalyptic sci-fi book where Earth is destroyed and humans from the Moon and Mars go on a rescue mission

Tags: story-identification, audio-book

I'm looking for a book of which I listened to the audio book a while ago. It was set in the future where humans have colonized the solar system. One ultra-rich man basically bought an asteroid and turned it into a habitat for himself and many other people. This man is an explorer and desperately wants to be the first to explore outside of the solar system, but they haven't discovered a way of going faster than light.

Then a mysterious alien force* just shows up out of the blue and hovers above Earth for a while abducting military equipment and personnel, all resistance is futile as they can seemingly sedate humans from a distance. These aliens then proceed to blow  up a large bomb near the center of the Earth sending it into a spiral of ever worsening natural disasters but for some reason don't do the same to the human settlements on the Moon or on Mars or out in the Asteroid belt. The humans then start a massive rescue campaign trying to rescue as many people from Earth as possible.

The reader then follows some of the abducted humans for a while, they get trained and used as slave soldiers to the aliens. We now learn that these aliens are one of 4 massive space empires that have subjugated many other alien species and keep them as servants. One of these races secretly decides to help the humans, after about a year of planning they seize control of one of the massive alien trading stations and use its FTL capability to return to the solar system to bring word of what happened. The humans now are in a race for survival as the alien overlords want to eradicate them, but we humans do what we do in a sci-fi story and valiantly fight on and form alliances with other races and start an uprising.

*These aliens are a large arachnid race whose home planet was destroyed during their eternal war with themselves, nowadays the thing on their home planet is the council (their leadership) who is determined by strength, to become more powerful you need to challenge and kill your superior.

I listened to this about 5-6 years back, so somewhere around 2013 and 2015. It was quite new at the time, being book 1 and 2 in a proposed Pentalogy.

Comment: Pieces of this sound like The Forge of God.

Comment: @StephenCollings The only thing in common with the OPs description and the The Forge of God, is aliens dropping a bomb into the center of the Earth.

Comment: @PeterM haha I finally found it :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book series is called [Galactic Empire Wars](https://www.amazon.it/Galactic-Empire-Wars-Destruction-English-ebook/dp/B00JL5HU6W), it's a military science fiction series written by Raymond L. Weil. The book starts of with Mason Randle, who is a ultra-rich owner of a huge mining corporation and who owns an asteroid, which is not only his base of operations but also his and many other people's home. Then an alien race called the "Kleese" come to earth, kidnap a bunch of military personnel, to serve as conscripts, and fire a missile that burrows into the core and detonates destroying earth. From there on we follow two storylines, one following the kidnapped personnel and the other following the survivors in the solar system trying to save as many humans as possible.

Instead basically copying [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184141/111034) (unaccepted) answer on another question, I'll just link it and the [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/135783-galactic-empire-wars) page.

Comment: Hey, it's great that you found it.  Could you add a bit of detail about the book?